# Getting RTK-precision GPS with arduino devices like NavSpark?

Tags: gps, wireless

In trying to learn how to create a reasonably precise 3d model of my (very hilly) property, I stumbled across a product called Navspark, which appears to be a $22 arduino-compatible development board, with an RTK-capable (and RTKlib-compatible) GPS chip.

The idea with RTK is that a reference-position base-station transmits its positional error to a mobile unit, giving the mobile unit cm-level precision relative to the position of the base station. The error calculation is computationally intensive, but apparently within the capabilities of a Pi.

Is it actually possible to build an RTK-capable mobile/base pair using low-priced equipment like this?  Can you link a howto or project example?

Comment: The $22 Nacsparc ( http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/navspark-arduino-compatible-development-board-with-gps/ ) doesn't appear to do RTK compatible GPS info.  For that you need the $80 NS-RAW : http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/ns-raw-carrier-phase-raw-measurement-output-gps-receiver/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the http://www.navspark.com.tw/tutorial-4 tutorial?  It seems to indicate you need a couple of the more capable $80 NS-RAW units with carrier-phase info rather than the less capable $22 NAV-SPARC plain GPS units.

The RTK system doesn't transmit only its positional error, (which it knows from external information) but also communicates the phase information for the particular channels, and then the RTK software re-calculates the positions of both using common sets of satellites and the phase info.  With the same framework, it knows the relative positions accurately, and with assumptions about the location of the base station, it can correct mobile station

This isn't an arduino problem, unless you are asking about porting RTKlib to something arduino.

Comment: It appears that NavSpark uses the same Venus 822A microcontroller as the NS-RAW, and some random blog article I read seemed to be saying that it was therefore capable of RTK.  Somehow missed their tutorial links, thanks.